# Extracting characters between double quotes

Tags: lua, find, lua-patterns

In my project, I need to extract some parameters from a settings file.
Below is a section of the line that I am reading, the parameter I need to extract is the Program Prefix.

```
...  ProgramPrefix="" ReceiveTimeout="80000" ...
```

I need to extract what is between the double quotes for ProgramPrefix. The problem is that in-between these quotes can be any alphanumeric character, symbol, space, or no character at all.

Below is my current solution for extracting any character before the second double-quote, the problem doesn't work for the case of anything being between the double quotes

```
    EOPdefL = string.find(line,"ProgramPostfix=")
    EOPdef = string.match(line,'([^"]+)',EOPdefL+16)
```

When there is nothing in-between the double quotes the output for EOPdef is:

```
EOPdef = ReceiveTimeout=
```

I would like EOPdef to just return an empty string if there are no characters.

```
EOPdef = ""
```

---

EDIT: lhf and Piglet provided a working resolution. The character class to capture 0 or more characters in between double quotes is the following:

```
'"(.-)"'
```

Implementing this character class into my solution results in the following code:

```
SOPdefL = string.find(line,"ProgramPrefix=")
SOPdef = string.match(line,'"(.-)"',SOPdefL+14)
```

Comment: Try `s:match('ProgramPrefix="(.-)"')`.

Answer (score 1):

one issue with your pattern is that you're trying to match one or more (`+`) non-doublequote characters. You need to match 0 or more, shortest match (`-`).

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

Most obvious as lhf already suggested you capture 0 or more characters between double quotes.

```
str:match('ProgramPrefix="(.-)"')
```

or you capture a balanced double quote pair and get its contents

```
str:match('ProgramPrefix=%b""'):sub(2,-2)
```